# Draw Graphics on JPanel as insert opertaion on JTextArea are made

Tags: graphics, jpanel, graphics2d, documentlistener

Hello Everyone and thx in advance.
 So my problem is I want to draw on a JPanel something on condition on what's been inserted in the JtextArea is this correct? : 
DocumentListener to check on the insert operation :

```
protected class MyDocumentListener  extends JPanel implements   javax.swing.event.DocumentListener {
    @Override
public void changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
        // text has been altered in the textarea

        }
    @Override
public void insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) 
    {
            // text has been added to the textarea 

        try { 
           //if not prompt Line
            if (!Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(Traffic.getLineCount()-1),
              Traffic.getLineEndOffset(Traffic.getLineCount()-1)-              Traffic.getLineStartOffset(Traffic.getLineCount()-1)).contains(">>"))
      {//if a line after a replace has been inserted

          if (Traffic.getLineCount()  == (lastreplace + 2) ) 
          {
        System.err.println(Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace),
                            Traffic.getLineEndOffset(lastreplace) - 
                                    Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace)));
               PortArchitecture (Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace),
                            Traffic.getLineEndOffset(lastreplace) - 
                                    Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace)));

               lastreplace +=1;

          }


            else//last line when it's not detected by the previous condition it'll be consumed here
          {
               System.err.println(Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace),
                            Traffic.getLineEndOffset(lastreplace) - 
                                    Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace)));
             PortArchitecture (Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace),
                            Traffic.getLineEndOffset(lastreplace) - 
                                    Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace))); 
          }
      }
        Traffic.setCaretPosition(Traffic.getDocument().getLength());

        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TrafficSerialPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
  public void removeUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
  // text has been removed from the textarea

}
 }
```

Methode to check the condition and draw on the JPanel :

```
public void PortArchitecture (String line) throws BadLocationException 
{

 Graphics2D gfx = (Graphics2D)graphicPanel.getGraphics();
    String [] valuesId = new String [2];
    valuesId = line.split(":");
    /**switch (valuesId[0])
    {
        case "Port Number" : draw();
    }*/
    if(valuesId[0].contains("Port number"))
    {

     gfx.drawString("(PN)", 30, 10);
     gfx.drawString(valuesId[1],30, 140);
}
    if(valuesId[0].contains("Port Extension"))
    {
        gfx.drawString("(EXT)", 100, 10);
        gfx.drawString(valuesId[1], 100, 140);
      //  draw(g);
}
    if(valuesId[0].contains("Forward Extension"))
    {
        gfx.drawLine(140,80,140,110);
      //  draw(g);
}
    if(valuesId[0].contains("ON-HOOK"))
    {
      //  draw(g);
}
    if(valuesId[0].contains("OFF-HOOK"))
    {
       // draw(g);
}
    if(valuesId[0].contains("Forward status"))
    {
        if(valuesId[1].contains("FORWARDED"))
        {
           // draw(g);
        }
        else
        {
           // draw(g);
        }
}
    if(valuesId[0].contains("Dialing"))
    {
        //get dialed number
        //draw(g);
}

}
```

And another thing : I have some result concerning Showing some drawings but when I minimize the application all the graphics are gone.I know I need to call the repaint() but I don't know when and how.
    Help please!

Answer (score 0):

So I've learn it the hard way but all drawing must be in the paintComponent() method.so in my case I need 3 classes(this is for anyone intrested) : 
  - the first to initialize the JTextArea and add the documentListener to it.
  - the 2nd is the DocumentListener class.
  - and the third will be a class that extends from JPanel(or JComponent) and contains the method paintComponent().

hope it'll help !